# How to convert PDF figures to EPS while keeping the original quality?

Tags: pdf, latex, eps, file-conversion, pdflatex

I have 10 figures (graphs and schematics) in PDF format to be published in a journal.

The journal accepts the figures only in the EPS format to correctly locate them when it compiles the Latex file containing my article.

What would be the best way to convert my PDF figures to EPS while maintaining their quality?

Comment: Tell your journal publisher that modern LaTeX/pdflatex/lualatex/xelatex versions can include PDF-based graphics directly into their PDF output.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Ghostscript

You can use the most recent release of Ghostscript, v9.16, with the `eps2write` device to extract page 4 from *some.pdf* as an EPS:

gs -o some.eps -sDEVICE=eps2write -dFirstPage=4 -dLastPage=4 some.pdf

However, don't use an older version of Ghostscript (which has only the `epswrite` device, not `eps2write`), because this would create only PostScript Level 1 (large file size, lots of rasterization, not-so-good quality in some cases...).

The `eps2write` device creates PostScript level 2.

### 2. `pdftops` (by XPDF/Foolabs or by the Poppler fork)

You can also use the command line tool `pstopdf`, like this:

```
pdftops -level3 -eps -origpagesizes -f 4 -l 4 some.pdf some-page4.eps
```

This would create PostScript Level 3 EPS output. To see more command line options, type `pdftops -h`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool such as ghostscript or one of its front-ends.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best quality EPS can be achieved using Acrobat and then save as EPS.

However, in any case, check the results, because (E)PS is less capable than PDF, and certain features (such as transparency or overprinting) may not work properly when exporting as EPS.